# yii active form validation on modal dialog

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, validation, yii, modal-dialog

I'm trying to validate CActiveForm on modal dialog. I use bootstrap.
The problem is modal dialog. When I read the contents of form during the load of main html page JavaScriopt validation works, but when I load the contents on click of button, validation scrips are gone.
**Here is the view of calling page**

```
<?php
/* @var $this SiteController */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name . ' - Все магазины';
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Shops',
);

$jsCreate = "$(\".createShop\").click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    var url = '?r=site/editShop';
    $(target).find(\".modal-dialog\").load(url);
});";
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScript('create-shop-script',$jsCreate,CClientScript::POS_READY);

$jsEdit = "$(\".editShop\").click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target).find(\".modal-dialog\").load(url);
});";
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScript('edit-shop-script',$jsEdit,CClientScript::POS_READY);


$jsDelete = "$(\".deleteShop\").click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target).find(\".modal-dialog\").load(url);
});";
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScript('delete-shop-script',$jsDelete,CClientScript::POS_READY);
?>

<h2>Все объекты</h2>
 <!-- I created separate dialog for shop and warning because on open it shows the previous content while forming the new one 
      and I don't want to show shop elements on warning and vise versa -->
<!-- modal dialog for shop -->
<div id="shopModal" class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

    </div>
</div>

<!-- modal warning dialog -->
<div id="warningModal" class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

    </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Название <span class="hidden-xs">объекта</span></th>
            <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok visible-xs"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Статус активности"></span><span class="hidden-xs">Статус</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php foreach($shops as $shop) :?>
    <?php $disabled = ($shop->active) ?'' :'gray'?>
    <tr>            
                <td><span class="<?php echo $disabled; ?>"><?php echo $shop->name; ?></span></td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo ($shop->active) ?"<span data-toggle='tooltip' title='Активен' class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span>" :"<span data-toggle='tooltip' title='Неактивен' class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close'></span>" ?>
                    &nbsp; <a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#shopModal' class="editShop" href="?r=site/editShop&amp;id=<?php echo $shop->id; ?>"><span data-toggle='tooltip' title='Редактировать объект' class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
                    &nbsp; <a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#warningModal' class="deleteShop" href="?r=site/deleteShop&amp;id=<?php echo $shop->id; ?>"><span data-toggle='tooltip' title='Удалить объект' class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a>
                </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<button style='float:right;' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#shopModal' class="createShop btn btn-primary"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Добавить объект"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> <span class="hidden-xs">Добавить объект</span></span></button>
```

**This is the view of form, that appears inside modal dialog**

```
<?php
/* 
   @var $this SiteController 
   @var $form CActiveForm */
?>
<?php
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'shop-form',
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array(
                'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        ),
        'htmlOptions'=> array('class'=>'bottom0',),
        'action'=>"$url&id={$model->id}",
));?>   
  <div class="modal-content panel-primary">
      <div class="modal-header panel-heading">
          <button type="button" class="close panel-title" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Закрыть">×</span></button>  
        <h4 class="modal-title panel-title"><?php echo $title;?></h4>
      </div> <!-- end modal-header -->

      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">              
              <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('data-toggle'=>'tooltip', 'title'=>'Название', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Название', 'maxlength'=>'50')); ?>
              <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
        </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label data-toggle="tooltip" title="Статус активноси">
                  <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'active') .' '. $form->label($model,'active') . $form->error($model,'active'); ?>
              </label>
          </div>
      </div> <!-- end modal-body -->


      <div class="modal-footer">
          <!-- Save button -->
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Сохранить"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> <span class="hidden-xs">Сохранить</span></span></button>
          <!-- Cancel button -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Отменить"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> <span class="hidden-xs">Отменить</span></span></button>
     </div> <!-- end modal-footer -->
  </div>
 <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

**This is my Shops model**

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "shops".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'shops':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $active
 */

class Shops extends CActiveRecord
{

public function tableName()
{
    return 'shops';
}

public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('name', 'length', 'max'=>255),
        array('active', 'length', 'max'=>1),
        array('id, name, active', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

public function relations()
{
    return array();
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'name' => 'Name',
        'active' => 'Active',
    );
}


public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}
}
```

**This is my site controller that deals with shop create/update/delete**

```
public function actionEditShop($id=null)
{
        if (!$this->checkAuthenticated()) return;


       if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='shop-form')
        {
          echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
        $model = $this->loadShop($id);
        if(isset($_POST['Shops']))
        {   
            // create/update shop               
            $fields = $_POST['Shops'];
            $fields['id'] = $id;
            $model->attributes=$fields;

            if($model->save())
                    $this->redirect(array('shops'));
        } else {
            // open form to create/update                
            $this->renderPartial('classifier',array('model'=>$model, 'title'=>'Объект', 'url'=>'?r=site/editShop'), false, true);
        }
}

    public function actionDeleteShop($id, $confirmed=null)
{
        if (!$this->checkAuthenticated()) return;
        $model = $this->loadShop($id);
        if (isset($confirmed)){
    $model->delete();
    $this->redirect(array('shops'));
        } else {
            $this->renderPartial('warning',array('url'=>"?r=site/deleteShop&id=$id&confirmed=1",));
        }
}

    private function loadShop($id=null)
{
        if ($id){
    $model=Shops::model()->findByPk($id);
    if($model===null)
        throw new CHttpException(404,"Объект под номером $id не существует.");
        } else {
            $model = new Shops; // creates with active='1'
            $model->active = '1';
        }
        return $model;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly tell your controller to include your scripts using the `processOutput` parameter of [`renderPartial()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail). When set, [`processOutput()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#processOutput-detail) is called which:

> Postprocesses the output generated by `render()`. This method is invoked
>   at the end of render`()` and `renderText()`. If there are registered
>   client scripts, this method will insert them into the output at
>   appropriate places. If there are dynamic contents, they will also be
>   inserted. This method may also save the persistent page states in
>   hidden fields of stateful forms in the page.

You should also uncomment

```
$this->performAjaxValidation($model);
```

and look at [Yii renderpartial (proccessoutput = true) Avoid Duplicate js request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188391/yii-renderpartial-proccessoutput-true-avoid-duplicate-js-request) if you use `processOutput`.

Comment: I changed, but no way

Comment: Are the validation scripts appearing in the code now?

Comment: Sorry. There was an incorrect part. Now I changed all parts. Please note, that the form is loading on modal dialog after rendering the page, so the validation javascript does not appear on resulting page. I compared it with Yii login dialog. There are a couple of validation scrips that is not present after moving the form into modal dialog

Comment: Are these missing scripts your own or the default Yii scripts?